# PhD research results in postdoc talk presentation

Tags: early-career

I am a PhD candidate and have been invited to visit two labs where I had applied for postdoc positions after initial online interviews. My question is regarding the content of my talk, which I think should include my PhD research questions as well as a big picture of my research interest. I was wondering about the following:

1. I am still working on getting results with respect to an important question before my final defense. Should I include that as ongoing work in the slides and mention that this question is being currently worked on?

   - Because this would be a significant contribution, however I don't have the results yet. Does that leave an awful impression since my results are still incomplete and it can leave the audience to wonder if and when I will get those results? I do have results on the other questions I have addressed.
2. Is it recommended that I have some idea about how my skills/ interests would tie with the research interest at the lab and include that in the talk?

Answer (score 6):

Probably nobody's research is ever complete: it is always work in progress to some extent.Your audience are not there to hear your final conclusions. What they want to know is whether you, your skills, your research experience, your research attitudes are in line with their own organisation.

So, talk about 2 with examples from your own research.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is good if you can tie your research interests with those of the lab. If you are hired you will be working, at least in part, on their goals, not just your own. This can depend on the nature of the position, of course.

And yes, it is *great* that you have uncompleted work in progress. The opposite can sometimes give the impression that you've done all you are capable of and don't have additional ideas. A new PhD is in a really good position if she or he can carry away ideas, partially developed, that will lead to future publications. This is especially true, for someone who wants an academic career, if those ideas can be passed on to future students who will also help advance the work.